# checking if a process contains a name

Tags: vb.net, process

I can check process a by using:

```
dim Proc as process() = Process.GetProccessByName("flashplayerplugin")
```

but since `flashplayerplugin` has a version included in the process name, my program won't detect it,
because the process name is something like `flashplayerplugin_34_21_6.exe`

So how can I check if a process name contains `flashplayerplugin`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could get all processes and the apply a Linq Any extension to find if one of the current running processes has a ProcessName that starts with your search string

```
Dim procs = Process.GetProcesses()
Dim flashRunning = procs.Any(Function(x) x.ProcessName.StartsWith("flashplayerplugin"))
if flashRunning Then
    Console.WriteLine("Flash player is running")
End If
```

Comment: a 32 bit process cannot access a 64 bit process < error

Comment: Just had to restart the IDE. working fine. thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you need to return all running **flashplayerplugin** Processes then use the following code:

```
Dim fppProcesses = Array.FindAll(Process.GetProcesses, Function(x) x.ProcessName.Contains("flashplayerplugin"))
```